# Choix de construction de la locution « Tiers temps » (éducation)

Tags: usage

> Majoration du temps imparti pour un candidat en situation de handicap,
>   qui ne peut excéder le tiers du temps normalement prévu pour l'examen.
>   Les candidats peuvent bénéficier d’une majoration du temps imparti
>   pour une ou plusieurs épreuves de l’examen ou du concours, équivalente
>   au tiers de la durée fixée pour chacune des épreuves. Cette majoration
>   pourra être allongée au-delà du tiers temps eu égard à la situation
>   exceptionnelle du candidat et sur demande motivée du médecin désigné
>   par la CDAPH. — (Ministère de l'Éducation nationale, Circulaire
>   N°2006-215 du 26-12-2006, 2006)

Je me demande comment la locution nominale «tiers temps» a été construite ?
Pourquoi dit-on «tiers temps» et pas «tiers de temps» ou bien «temps tiers» ?
Est-ce une locution figée ?

Comment: Une piste possible: en parlant de durées contractuelles de travail, on dit un *plein-temps* pour un horaire de travail complet, et on a donc aussi les expressions *mi-temps* et *quart-temps*. *Tiers temps* tel qu'utilisé dans votre contexte peut être construit sur le même modèle ?

Comment: Il y a quelques centaines d'années, on parlait également du "tiers-état". Est-ce que ce n'était pas simplement la syntaxe à l'époque ?

Comment: c'est aussi comme ça qu'on appelle une période de jeu dans certains sport. Exemple, au hockey, la partie est découpée en trois tiers-temps. J'imagine que ça a la même origine

Comment: Ce tiers temps, c'est en quelque sorte un quatrième tiers-temps. cf. [Troisième mi-temps](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/troisi%C3%A8me_mi-temps).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Je me demande comment la locution nominale «tiers temps» a été construite ?

Les substantifs représentant la moitié de quelque chose sont souvent préfixés par **demi** ou **mi** :

- demi-dieu, demi-finale, demi-heure, demi-lune, demi-mesure, demi-portion...
- mi-août, mi-chemin, mi-course, mi-figue mi-raisin, mi-journée, mi-saison, mi-temps...

Sur le même principe, des substantifs ou locutions utilisent **tiers** :

- [Tiers-état](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiers_%C3%A9tat), [tiers-monde](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tiers-monde), tierce collision, [tiers payant](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiers_payant), [tiers-ordre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiers-ordre) et [tiers-point](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tiers-point).

Tierces et tiers signifient souvent ici *autre*, c'est à dire une troisième entité (personne, groupe de personnes, pays) qui intervient dans une affaire qui concerne deux entités (voire une seule). Il ne s'agit donc pas forcément d'un tiers au sens arithmétique (le Tiers-état représente 98% des électeurs en 1789).

Plus rares, mais toujours sur le même modèle, on trouve pour **quart** :

- [quart-monde](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quart-monde), quart-temps

Tiers-temps et quart-temps, plus récents que mi-temps, ont été construits à partir de ce dernier. Quand *mi*, *tiers* et *quart* s'appliquent au temps, on reste dans le domaine des fractions 1/2, 1/3 et 1/4.

Quart-monde a été construit sur le modèle de tiers-monde, et tiers-monde a été construit sur celui de tiers-état.

> Pourquoi dit-on «tiers temps» et pas «tiers de temps» ou bien «temps tiers» ?

Parce qu'on ne dit pas non plus *moitié de temps* ou *temps moitié*. *Temps tiers* aurait été possible mais ç'aurait été avec *tiers* signifiant *autre*, donc sans la composante mathématique.

*Tiers temps* est donc utilisé par analogie avec les [mi-temps](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mi-temps_(sport)), [tiers-temps](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiers_temps), et [quart-temps](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quart-temps) des épreuves sportives ou des horaires de travail ([mi-temps](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travail_%C3%A0_mi-temps)).

On retrouve aussi *tiers temps* dans le contexte du travail à durée déterminée. Le tiers temps peut y désigner le délai de carence durant lequel un employeur n'a pas le droit de réembaucher l'un de ses anciens salariés.

Ce même *[tiers temps](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9decine_du_travail_(sp%C3%A9cialit%C3%A9_m%C3%A9dicale_en_France)#L'action_sur_le_milieu_de_travail_(tiers_temps))* peut désigner le temps de présence en entreprise imposé aux médecins du travail (1/3 de leur temps de travail) en vue de l'amélioration des conditions de travail des employés.

Dans l'article faisant l'objet de la question, *tiers temps* représente un tiers de temps ajouté aux trois tiers existants, un peu comme l'eau dans la [recette de Picon-citron-curacao](https://fr.wikiquote.org/wiki/Marcel_Pagnol#Marius,_1926) de Marius (Marcel Pagnol).

> Est-ce une locution figée ?

En quelque sorte oui. Elle a le mérite d'être à la fois plus précise et concise que *temps additionnel*.

Answer (score 0):

Réponse fondée sur les commentaires :

Une piste possible: en parlant de durées contractuelles de travail, on dit un plein-temps pour un horaire de travail complet, et on a donc aussi les expressions mi-temps et quart-temps. Tiers temps tel qu'utilisé dans le présent contexte peut être construit sur le même modèle.

Par ailleurs, il y a quelques centaines d'années, on parlait également du *tiers-état*.
De plus, c'est aussi comme ça qu'on appelle une période de jeu dans certains sport. Exemple, au hockey, la partie est découpée en trois tiers-temps. 
Ce tiers temps, c'est en quelque sorte un quatrième tiers-temps. cf. Troisième mi-temps.

Bizarrement, la locution n'apparaît pas ici:

http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tiers%20temps

La majorité des dictionnaires en ligne que j'ai consultés n'en parlent pas aussi.