# Est-il correct de dire « assurance tierce » pour désigner l'assurance au tiers ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Selon le dictionnaire, « tiers » est un adjectif qui signifie « troisième » ainsi qu'un nom qui signifie « troisième personne ».

« Assurance au tiers » est donc l'assurance à la troisième personne (celle à être indemnisée), la première et deuxième personne étant le preneur d'assurance et l'assureur (ou vice versa).

« Assurance tierce », par contre, ne me semble pas avoir de logique.

Ce qui me fait poser la question est que quand on recherche « assurance tierce » sur Google, on a quand même [plus de 8 000 résultats](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22assurance%20tierce%22).

Comment: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=assurance+tierce%2Cassurance+au+tiers&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cassurance%20au%20tiers%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cassurance%20au%20tiers%3B%2Cc0) indique aucun résultat pour « assurance tierce »

Answer (score 1):

Non il n'est pas correct de dire cela dans ce cadre là mais "assurance au tiers" a en effet cette signification. En d'autres termes, une assurance au tiers, en opposition à une assurance tout risque, est un contrat d'assurance qui ne couvre pas tous les dommages mais seulement ceux causés à une tierce personne par l'assuré.

Une "assurance tierce" serait plutôt l'assurance d'une tierce partie/personne. Contrairement à "au tiers", "tierce" est ici un adjectif s'appliquant à "assurance". Ce qui désigne l'assurance de quelqu'un d'autre.

Answer (score 1):

Tiers est un nom commun masculin mais aussi un adjectif. Dans ce dernier cas, il a un féminin qui est *tierce*.

On pourra alors parler d'*assurance **tierce collision***, c'est à dire assurance couvrant les dommages causés par collision avec des tiers (biens ou personnes), et donc ne couvrant pas ses propres dommages ni les accidents où aucun tiers n'est impliqué. L'assurance *tout risque* est dans ces cas nécessaire. *Tierce collision* est ici une locution, comme par exemple un [tiers temps](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32656/choix-de-construction-de-la-locution-tiers-temps-%C3%A9ducation/32694#32694).

Utilisé telle quelle, l'expression *assurance tierce* est donc un contresens ou un barbarisme, mais elle devient correcte quand elle est suivie de *collision*.